# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function stats_cdf_t()

Tags: php, excel

I have to calculate an Excel formula(F.DIST.RT) in PHP. but receiving an error.
e.g,

```
F.DIST.RT(4, 2, 1)
```

As defined here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stats-cdf-t.php

Comment: According to help, you are calculating CDF(x=4 ν=2); is it what you really want?

Anyway, the error message suggests a missing dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed PECL and Stat library in PHP to fix this problem.

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
sudo apt-get install php7.4-dev
sudo pecl install stats-2.0.3
```

then added `extension=stats.so` to my php.ini
restart apache.

Comment: After following above steps:
To match the output of this function with Excel's TDIST function:
As @yahya Ayyoub said: you must take 1 - the value.

Answer (score 1):

**First**

you need to install PECL and Stat library in PHP to fix this problem.

```
 sudo apt-get install php-pear
 sudo apt-get install php7.4-dev
 sudo pecl install stats-2.0.3
```

then added extension=stats.so to my php.ini

**Second**

restart apache.

**Third**

In order to match the output of this function with Excel's TDIST function, you must take 1 - the value.  For example, for a two-tailed T-distribution for x=4 and degrees of freedom=2, the formula would be:

```
(1 - stats_cdf_t(4, 2, 1)) * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated from the reference page, you need to install the correct php extension to call stats_cdf_t function, as it is not included inside php standard library.

You can use [pecl](https://pecl.php.net/package/stats) to install it on your server.